# PHP array unique does not work like expected

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I have a problem with array_unique() in PHP.
Here is my code:

```
$filterGroupsArray = ['', 'a', 'a', 'b'];
print_r($filterGroupsArray);
array_unique($filterGroupsArray);
print_r($filterGroupsArray);
```

The output is

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => a [2] => a [3] => b ) Array ( [0] => [1] => a [2] => a [3] => b )
```

but I am expecting

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => a [2] => a [3] => b ) Array ( [0] => [1] => a [2] => b )
```

What did I do wrong?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_unique returns a new array with the duplicate values removed.

```
$uniqueArray = array_unique($filterGroupsArray);
print_r($uniqueArray);
```